# xref-find-definition goes to constructed init.el by doom emacs

Tags: doom, xref

I think this is doom emacs specific problem.

Doom collects `autoload` functions into an `./local/etc/@/init.el` file
And when I do M-. (which is mapped to doom's `+lookup/definition` and in turn it tries `xref-find-definition`

, I land on the init.el file. (for instance I look for `org-agenda` and ends up landing in the init.el)

Is there a way to prevent this, and let it find the original source file?

Comment: I keep hearing these horrible things about Doom Emacs. Why does anyone use it?

Comment: well, for me, it's a window that shows me new things. 

since it has collected many stuff. I can try those out without me taking much time researching those possibilities